# Verify only specific interaction within a pool of methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm currently writing black box test and I have to verify with Mockito that one method out of a pool of methods is called with specific arguments. It doesn't matter if a specific method was called, but **one** of the methods has to be called at all. Also if the methods get called I want to verify that they are only called with specific arguments.

At a concrete level:

I have this class which is mocked and injected to my black box:

```
class Mock {
    void option1(String arg1)
    void option2(String arg1, int arg2)
    void option3(String arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    void otherMethod()
}
```

Within the blackbox, one or multiple of the "optionX" methods are called once or multiple times.

Now I want to verify that at least one of the "optionX" methods was called within the black box and that if any of the "optionX" methods are called, it's only called with specific arguments.

The current test code looks like this

```
Mock mock = spy(realObject);
blackbox.doBlackboxStuff(mock);

verify(mock, atLeast(1)).option1("Test");
verify(mock, atLeast(1)).option2("Test", 1);
verify(mock, atLeast(1)).option3("Test", 1, 2);
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);
```

Separate "atLeast(1) verifications" like above won't work, because then every method has to be called. Also, I can't guarantee, that the black box won't call otherMethod(), so that verifyNoMoreInteractions will fail, even if I don't care about the otherMethod() call.

Is there an elegant way to solve this (or at least **a** way)?

Comment: this is one of those situations when you should more than likely change the code so it's very clear what happens, or not test it at all. Checking that a method from a pool of methods is run is not very useful. What are the rules for each method to be called? why is method1 called as opposed to method2? How do you build this pool of methods in the first place. If you don't have a clear requirement and clear expectations then you shouldn't write a "test" for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way which is a bit hacky but should work:

```
MockingDetails details = Mockito.mockingDetails(mock);
Collection<Invocation> invocations = details.getInvocations();

for(Invocation invocation: invocations){
   if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(invocation.getRawArguments()){
      return;
   }
}

fail();
```

So basically if at least one of the invocations contains any arguments your test passes. Assuming `otherMethod` has no arguments as in the example.

If more customization is needed please reference: [MockingDetails](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.29/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html) and [Invocation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.29/org/mockito/invocation/Invocation.html)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that all your methods `option1` ... `option3` call some common helper method.  At least the similarity of their names indicate that there also might be some similarity in functionality.  Now, let's assume they all call `helper`.  Then, instead of checking if any of the `optionx` methods was called, you could check if `helper` was called.

Comment: Unfortunately the common method called is private.